# How to Install and Use Apache OpenNLP in Windows Eclipse

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, installation, opennlp

I have downloaded the tar file from :
http://opennlp.apache.org/cgi-bin/download.cgi
I wish to use the libraries on an android application, which requires NLP.
I use windows and IDE(ECLIPSE) at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

How do i import these libraries etc. from the tar file i downloaded, so that i can code in android/java in eclipse and can install on an android app.

Also suggest some NLPs i can use on an android app.

Comment: Alternatively  if you could tell how to start using Stanford CoreNLP